# Python insert tab in string

Tags: python

I just began learning Python. I'm not sure how to insert tab in string.
For instance, how can i insert tab to the right of "World" in the strings below:

```
example = '    Hello World'
```

Everytime I use Tab after "World" a drop down menu appears, how can I avoid that? thanks!
I tried using `\t`, but then 
`example.lstrip()` gives the result of `Hello World\t`, instead of `Hello World`

Thanks for the answers. I used `example = '    Hello World\t'`, it works.
`print(example.lstrip())` gives the result: `Hello World`    , without `\t`

Comment: `lstrip` strips the left only... `strip` strips both sides.

Comment: Just use example[:-1]  to get rid of final tab character.

Comment: your editor is creating the drop down. Are you using IDLE? Don't. `str.lstrip` only strips whitespace off the left side, leaving the trailing `\t` intact.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The dropdown error is because of the editor you are using. Just try using plain notepad++. It's working! I tried.

```
print "Hello World\t",
print "hi"
```

Just to make sure that there is tab after the first print, print one more statement. you will come to visual it. Make sure to use comma ',' after print to stay in the same line if you are using python 2.7. Else use end="" for python 3+ to stay in the same line.